# Proving divergence for piecewise defined sums

Tags: calculus

Show that the series $\sum(-1)^{n-1}b_n$, where $b_n=1/n$ if $n$ is odd and $b_n=1/n^2 $ if $n$ is even, divergent.

I'm completely stuck on how to start the problem. I was told that I should use proof by contradiction, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n-1}b_n=
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac1{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n)^2}\right)=
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{(2n)^2-(2n+1)}{(2n)^2(2n+1)}\right)
$$
which diverges, since
$$
\left(\frac{(2n)^2-(2n+1)}{(2n)^2(2n+1)}\right)\sim_{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the series $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges. Let $s_{2m}$ be the partial sum $\sum_1^{2m} a_n$. Then the sequence $(s_{2m})$ converges. 
Note that $s_{2m}=p_m-q_m$, where
$$p_m=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{2k-1}$$
and 
$$q_m=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
We know that the sequence $(q_m)$ converges. Since $p_m=s_{2m}+q_m$, and $(s_{2m})$ and $(q_m)$ converge, it follows that $(p_m)$ converges. But the sequence $(p_m)$ diverges, so we have reached a contradiction.